# it is possible to run more then one app under mod_aspdotnet?

Tags: asp.net, apache

I have an apache server runing on win 2003.

i configure the mod_aspdotnet like 
this guide [link text](http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/09/11/424852.aspx)

to enable asp.net web app
and all ok. **just for one web app...!**

is there any way to configure more the one app?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should be possible. You'd just have to add another  to the Apache config and point it to where your second application resides on the filesystem.

Comment: first, thanks for the replay.
I added another ifmoudole just below to original one
it seems he go to the original app with the new alias too.
just another alias name to the original app..